# How to change form action attribute value based on selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've looked at countless examples on here and not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to change the form action based on the selected value from a dropdown menu.

Basically, the HTML looks like this:

```
<form id="storetable" autocomplete="off" action="" method="post">
<label>STORE:</label>
  <input type="text" list="storeID" name="store" placeholder="Choose a store..." required>
       <datalist id="storeID">
          <option value="cwb_coins">Causeway Bay</option>
          <option value="wc_coins">Wan Chai</option>
          <option value="lck_coins">Lai Chi Kok</option>
          <option value="tp_coins">Tai Po</option>
       </datalist>
</form
```

javascript:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#storeID").change(function(){
   var url =  $(this).children(":selected").text(); //get the selected option value
   switch (url) 
  {
   case "cwb_coins":
   $("#storetable").attr('action','cwb_coin_code.php');
   //changing action attribute of form to cwb_coin_code.php
   break;
   case "wc_coins":
   $("#storetable").attr('action','wc_coin_code.php');
   break;
   case "lck_coins":
   $("#storetable").attr('action','lck_coin_code.php');
   break;
   case "tp_coins":
   $("#storetable").attr('action','tp_coin_code.php');
   break;
   default:
       $("#storetable").attr('action', '#');
   }
   }); 
 }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe `$("#storetable").attr("action", ....);`

Comment: like so?  $("#storetable").attr("action" + 'cwb_coin_code.php');

Answer (score 0):

It should be like, on change, get the value, and set the action attribute to 'cwb_coin_code.php' + value;

```
  $("#storeID").change(function() {
    $("#storetable").attr("action", "cwb_coin_code.php" + $(this).val());
  });
```

Comment: what do I set my form action to? this still does not insert the record into cwb_coins. If I replace my form action with cwb_coin_code.php it works, but I need it to select that dynamically through the drop down